# Problem with width in horizontal scrolltrigger

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrolltrigger

I have a problem in my code with container's width, when I scrolling. For example, I don't see my las item in the list. I can't understand why there is this problem. I use ScrollTrigger and GSAP for this horizontal scroll. Also active element is wrong, because I can't scroll to end of list

``https://codepen.io/afonin_vlad/pen/BadoYqM```

Answer (score 1):

Your getMaxWidth() only adds the offsetWidth, but forgets to add the 30px margin-left.